# Method for simplifying complex logic tables

Tags: algorithms, logic, boolean-algebra

Not sure if this is the right StackExchange site, but back in college (20 years ago) I took a *Digital Systems Design* class where we learned how to reverse engineer a boolean function to meet the requirements set forth in a logic table.

If I recall correctly, the logic table looked *something* like this:

```
Input A         Input B        Input C       Output (z)
=======================================================
T               T              T             F
T               T              F             T
T               F              T             F
T               F              F             T
F               T              T             F
F               T              F             T
F               F              T             T
F               F              F             T
```

This means there are five (5) truth conditions:

```
F(A,B,C) = true when = (A + B + !C) ||
                       (A + !B + !C) ||
                       (!A + B + !C) ||
                       (!A + !B + C) ||
                       (!A + !B + !C)
```

There was some type of math involved but it allowed you to take the logic table and convert it into a simplified boolean function that accepted A, B, C (any number of inputs) as arguments and always produced the desired output (`z`).

Can someone verify whether I've modeled this correctly, and perhaps help me work through this one simplification so that I can see it in action? I actually have to do this with a real-world logic table that's fairly complicated but if I see a simple example I should be able to extrapolate.

Comment: The full table directly specifies a sum of minterms. You can try [Boolean expression minimisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization#Boolean_expression_minimization) to reduce the number and/or length of terms. You can go multi-level expressions/logic.

Comment: Ahhh thanks @greybeard (+1) it _was_ simplification. I have updated my question with a simple table that could serve as an example.

Comment: (Or just $¬C ∨ ¬A¬BC$)

Comment: Very interesting, if you would be generous enough to provide an answer that shows how you arrived at that simplification, I would be grateful, would give you the green check, and would also be able to carry this with me on future problems -- thanks again!

Comment: [Karnaugh-Veitch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), actually. But the way you tabulated the minterms, it's not that hard to spot it there, too, especially if you swap the last two terms. (To think I left developing IC design tools one third of a century ago…)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm when the karnaug-veitch method becomes complex(> 4 variables)

Comment: You're thinking of [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).